# Django celery crontab every 30 seconds - is it even possible?

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks, cron, celery

Is it possible to run the django celery crontab very 30 seconds **DURING SPECIFIC HOURS**?

There are only settings for minutes, hours and days.

I have the crontab working, but I'd like to run it every 30 seconds, as opposed to every minute.

**Alternatively...**

Is it possible to turn the interval on for 30 seconds, and turn on the interval schedule only for a certain period of the day?

Answer (score 14):

[Very first example they have in the documentation is](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries)...

> *Example: Run the tasks.add task every 30 seconds.*
>
> ```
> from datetime import timedelta
>
> CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
>     "runs-every-30-seconds": {
>         "task": "tasks.add",
>         "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
>         "args": (16, 16)
>     },
> }
> ```

Comment: I need it to run every 30 seconds **DURING SPECIFIC HOURS**. I too came across the _very first example they have in the documentation_.

Comment: am also looking for a solution to this (and came across this post). would be really nice if timedelta could be combined w/crontab.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use

```
from datetime import timedelta

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=30))
def thirty_second_task():
   now = datetime.now()
   if now.hour == 12 or now.hour == 9:
       your code goes here`
```

That will run the function every thirty seconds, but it will only run your code if the hour value of the current time is 12 or 9.

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* need to do this and you need a solution quickly, you could resort to adding:
sleep <num_seconds>
into your script.
(obviously you'd need to add a parameter to your script to setup the sleep time to either 0 or 30 seconds and add the script twice to crontab, once with 0 as the parameter, secondly with 30).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with your alternative solution by scheduling another task to enable/disable the primary task:

```
# tasks.py
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask

@app.task
def toggle_thirty_second_task:
    # you would use whatever you named your task below
    thirty_second_tasks = PeriodicTask.objects.filter(name='runs-every-30-seconds')
    if thirty_second_tasks:
        # this returned an array, so we'll want to look at the first object
        thirty_second_task = thirty_second_tasks[0]
        # toggle the enabled value
        thirty_second_task.enabled = not thirty_second_task.enabled
        thirty_second_task.save()
```

Then just schedule this task using a crontab for the hours that you need to toggle. Alternatively, you could have a task scheduled to turn it on and one to turn it off and not deal with the toggling logic.

Hope this helps.

sc